# GHC: ghc gives clang error, but ghc --make works

Tags: haskell, ghc

Long story short: I have two `.hs` files, where `Main.hs` uses module `Lib.hs`

When I try to compile them as suggested by the book [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/writing-a-library-working-with-json-data.html), p 115, I got problems:

```
$ ghc -c Lib.hs
$ ghc -o main Main.hs Lib.o 
    [2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )
    Linking main ...
    duplicate symbol '_Lib_add1_info' in:
        ./Lib.o
        Lib.o
    duplicate symbol '_Lib_add1_closure' in:
        ./Lib.o
        Lib.o
    ld: 3 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    `clang' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
```

But, when I simply use `ghc --make`, it works fine

```
 $ ghc --make Main.hs
[1 of 2] Compiling Lib              ( Lib.hs, Lib.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )
Linking Main ...
    $ ls -1
    Lib.hi
    Lib.hs
    Lib.o
    Main
    Main.hi
    Main.hs
    Main.o
```

Can anyone explain why `ghc --make` works while simply `ghc` does not?

BTW, my ghc's version is

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.10.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [GHC docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using.html?highlight=make#ghc-flag---make):

> ```
> --make
> ```
>
> In this mode, GHC will build a multi-module Haskell program automatically, figuring out dependencies for itself. If you have a
> straightforward Haskell program, this is likely to be much easier, and
> faster, than using make. [..]
>
> This mode is the default if there are any Haskell source files mentioned on the command line, and in this case the `--make` option can
> be omitted.

Hence your line

```
ghc -o main Main.hs Lib.o
```

actually means

```
ghc -o main --make Main.hs Lib.o
```

which will compile and link `Main.hs` and all its dependencies (including `Lib.o`), adding another `Lib.o` during linking. This will link `Lib.o` twice, triggering the linker error reported by the OP.

I guess this was changed in GHC after Real World Haskell was written.